# Register Fields Error Messages in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the .NET framework 4.5.2, where are messages like the following in the code?

```
    'Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character.'

    'Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').'
```

I know that the rules are on the class RegisterViewModel (Models/AccountViewModels.cs) and on the class ApplicationUserManager (App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs).

Comment: The view(model) may have data annotations like `[Required]`. Model validator will use that to generate the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

open up `IdentityConfig.cs`

navigate to the line similar to

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator 
{ 
    RequiredLength = 6, 
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true, 
    RequireDigit = true, 
    RequireLowercase = true, 
    RequireUppercase = true, 
};
```

that's where it is setting the requirement. You can alter it to meet your requirements

as for the location of the msg

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

is going to populate result object and within

```
result.Errors
```

are where the error msg lives. it lives inside .NET identity logic and there is no way to config it atm. If you want to localize them you will have to do some string match and replace.